# Bit type in T-SQL

Tags: c#, sql-server, types, bit, sqldatareader

In my table, I use the bit type for `IsTrue` column.

When I execute the select command:

```
SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
```

I'm not sure that what would the `reader["isTrue"]` return ?

I tried doing the comparison

```
reader["isTrue"].ToString().Equals("0")
```

but it didn't work well. Can somebody tell me what I did incorrectly?

Comment: It "didn't work well"? What does that mean? What does `reader["isTrue"].ToString()` return?

Comment: it didn't work as I expected :)

Comment: When something doesn't work as expected, you should post how it did work and how you expected it to work.

Answer (score 6):

It returns a boolean value.

```
bool value = (bool)reader["IsTrue"];
```

If you know the index of the column in the result set, you can use:

```
bool value = reader.GetBoolean(index);
```

Comment: If you don't know the index of the column, `GetOrdinal` will tell you what it is.

Answer (score 0):

I like to do this with extension methods:

```
public static bool ToBool(this string theString)
    {
        bool result = false;
        bool.TryParse(theString, out result);
        return result;

    }
```

And in your code you can simply do this:

```
if(reader["isTrue"].ToBool())
{
}
```

The ToBool extension method will return true/false in the following cases:

- false if reader["isTrue"] returns DBNull.Value
- false if reader["isTrue"] returns 0 (as bit)
- true if reader["istrue"] returns 1 (as bit)

And it will never throw an exception when you execute it unless the "isTrue" column is not present in your result set, obviously.

Comment: There's no point in assigning `result = false;` since `bool.TryParse` will already set it to its default value (i.e. `false`). In C# 7 this could even be simplified to `bool.TryParse(theString, out bool result); return result;`.